# why are there multiple fcntl.h in linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, header-files

I write a c program which includes `fcntl.h` file. I search the file and get results as follow:

```
[xunyl@localhost csapp]$ find /usr/include/ -name "fcntl.h"
/usr/include/asm/fcntl.h
/usr/include/asm-generic/fcntl.h
/usr/include/linux/fcntl.h
/usr/include/sys/fcntl.h
/usr/include/bits/fcntl.h
/usr/include/fcntl.h

[xunyl@localhost csapp]$ grep -rn "O_RDONLY" /usr/include/
/usr/include/asm-generic/fcntl.h:19:#define O_RDONLY    00000000
/usr/include/linux/cdrom.h:32: *       -    drive = open("/dev/cdrom", O_RDONLY);
/usr/include/linux/cdrom.h:33: *       +    drive = open("/dev/cdrom", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
...
```

I find gcc calls `/usr/include/asm-generic/fcntl.h` actually when I put `#include <fcntl.h>` in program. I just wonder how gcc determines which "fcntl.h" should be called. Is there any call order or precedence ?

Comment: It depends on PATH settings, or gcc `-I` option.

Comment: take a look at [Search Path](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html)

Comment: @LPs: Why technically true, you would only ever include the one in `/usr/include`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One includes another which includes the next until the one with the definition is included.